# How do I properly change package name built with poetry?

Tags: python, package, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

I built a package using `poetry` package manager but I regret naming it because it sounds a bit childish.

Besides, because `poetry`'s default behavior is to force change the project's name to lower case (`SuperPackage` --> `superpackage`), it is difficult to import the package inside/outside the package's main directory.

Here's an example directory structure:

```
SuperPackage/
    - superpackage/
    - mysubpackage/
        - __init__.py
        - utils.py
        - foo.py
    - tests/
        - __init__.py
        - test_superpackage.py
    - poetry.lock
    - pyproject.toml
    - README.md
    - README.rst
    - .gitignore
```

Because of this structure,

```py
from SuperPackage.mysubpackage import utils # Works outside SuperPackage/ directory. Doesn't work inside SuperPackage/.
from superpackage.mysubpackage import utils # Works inside SuperPackage/. Doesn't work outside SuperPackage/ directory.
```

Now, I want to change `SuperPackage` to `nicepackage`.

How do I achieve this? I can't google it maybe because it's very uncommon or it's too obvious. Should I just change `"name"` field in `pyproject.toml` file?

However, I'm not sure if it's okay (and recommended) to change `"name"` field directly.

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "SuperPackage"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["John-Doe <johndoe@gmail.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
pandas = "^1.3.4"
matplotlib = "^3.4.3"
beautifulsoup4 = "^4.10.0"
```

Comment: Check out this reddit post. Some people answered on this question in the comment https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/uxd1fh/how_do_i_properly_change_package_name_built_with/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

Comment: Could you recreate the answer below?

Comment: The top-level import package is `mysubpackage` so the imports should be: `from mysubpackage import utils`. `SuperPackage` is the name of the "distribution package" which has nothing to do with the "import package": https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/packaging.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the name field in `pyproject.toml`, run `poetry update` (not sure that's needed but do it just in case?) and change the directories names.

Note that the name of the virtual environment on your computer will stay the same, but that probably isn't a problem as it only is a local ting.

Comment: Thanks for answering the old question! :)

Comment: I would recommend `poetry update` *and* `poetry install` which also performs a local editable package install. If the name of the package changes this is actually very important.

Comment: There also might be a need to uninstall the old local editable package with `pip uninstall my_old_package_name` if it was installed as well to avoid any problems. Haven't tested it though.